# Is it possible to add a php number counter variable to a twig template?

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I have a custom template setup for the paragraph module in Drupal 8. It so the user can add an accordion to the body copy if wanted. I have an accessible code snippet that I have written and use whenever I need accordions. It works fine except when I use it normally, its on a custom coded page so I can change the ID value on each one. As this will be a paragraph module that the user adds to the page as many time as the like, I need to somehow dynamically apply the ID numbers to the snippet - adding 1 to the number every time the user adds another accordion.

So below is the code that I use:

```
<div class="accord">
   <h2 class="toggleAccord">
      <button aria-controls="accord-1" aria-expanded="false">{{content.field_accordion_title}}</button>
   </h2>
   <div class="accordion-text" aria-hidden="true" id="accord-1">
      {{content.field_accordion_body}}
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  openAccordion();

  $(".toggleAccord button").click(function() {

    var btn = $(this);
    var toggle = btn.parent();
    var content = btn.parent().next();

    if (btn.attr('aria-expanded') === 'false') {
      // open
      $(content).slideDown();
      toggle.addClass('closeAccord');
      btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
      content.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');

    } else {
      // close
      $(content).slideUp();
      toggle.removeClass('closeAccord');
      btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      content.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

So I need the 'accord-1' to dynamically count up one every time an accordion is added. accord-2, accord-3 etc.

Is there a way I can replace the number with a php or jQuery variable so it automatically counts up?

Comment: This is the code that toggles (expand/collapse) an accordion when user clicks. Where is the code that actually makes a user able to *add* an accordion element ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can count the DOM  elements first. Then after counting and stocking this value in a variable, I would use ajax or xhr request to send this information to a php variable in my drupal side. Do you think you need a code suggestion to this?